# Numba vectorization slower than numpy with 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

In the following code, test_func_1 is about an order of magnitude slower than test_func_2. Is it impossible to improve on, or even match, numpy performance for this operation?

```
from numba import guvectorize
import numpy as np

@guvectorize(['void(float64[:,:,:], float64[:], float64[:,:,:])'], '(n,o,p),(n)->(n,o,p)', nopython=True)
def test_func_1(time_series, areas, res):
    for i in range(areas.size):
        area = areas[i]
        adjusted_area = (area / 10000.) ** .12  # used to adjust erosion
        for k in range(time_series.shape[0]):
            res[i, 0, k] = time_series[i, 0, k] * area
            res[i, 1, k] = time_series[i, 1, k] * adjusted_area
            res[i, 2, k] = time_series[i, 2, k] * area
            res[i, 3, k] = time_series[i, 3, k] * adjusted_area


def test_func_2(time_series, areas):
    array = np.swapaxes(time_series, 0, 2)
    array[:, :2] *= areas
    array[:, 2:] *= (areas / 10000.) ** .12
    return array

dummy = np.float32(np.random.randint(0, 10, (20, 5, 5000)))
areas = np.float32(np.random.randint(0, 10, 20))

test_func_1(dummy, areas)
test_func_2(dummy, areas)
```

Comment: I am getting around 80 u-sec for `test_func_2(dummy, areas)` with the given dataset. Is that really your bottleneck? Or are you just trying to learn numba? Or are you actually working with larger data?

Comment: I'm getting that `test_func_1` is about 2x slower. When you time it, are you timing it just once (which includes the jit compilation time) or are you timing subsequent calls which will have cached the compilation and will just be the runtime of the function?

Comment: It's simplified for the sake of clarity. I intend to use a similar function that will ultimately be called tens of thousands of times on very large 3d arrays.

Comment: Running it 1k times and taking the mean

Comment: Also, one general word of warning in case you hadn't noticed, but `np.swapaxes` in numpy>1.10 returns a view so in the example you're modifying `time_series` each time the function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JoshAdel noted in the comments, the key difference here is that your `numba` version is allocating and filling a new array, while the numpy is modifying the original in-place.

Adding an appropriate `.copy()` to the numpy one makes it slightly slower for me.  You could also have your numba version work in place - as far as I know not possible with a gufunc, but would be with a regular jit function if you don't need the broadcasting that a gufunc provides.

```
def test_func_2(time_series, areas):
    array = np.swapaxes(time_series, 0, 2).copy()
    array[:, :2] *= areas
    array[:, 2:] *= (areas / 10000.) ** .12
    return array

dummy = np.float32(np.random.randint(0, 10, (20, 5, 5000)))
areas = np.float32(np.random.randint(0, 10, 20))

%timeit test_func_1(dummy, areas)
1.21 ms ± 5.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit test_func_2(dummy, areas)
1.77 ms ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```